# Ubuntu Ralink RT5390 Help

Tags: wireless, ralink

just installed Ubuntu 19.10. I can't get my wireless adapter to work. I have an ASUS X54C, which uses the Ralink RT5390 PCI Wireless card. Can anyone help ?